# API Testing on mobile apps

Tags: android, ios, testing, automated-tests, profiling

I want tools to run API testing on closed mobile packages APK for Android or IPA for iOS. I want to intercept the connection and make sure that the API requests and responses matches specific signature.

Answer (score 0):

For API testing on APK or IPA packages with signature verification, use a proxy tool like Charles or Fiddler to intercept traffic. Bypass SSL pinning with Frida or Objection if needed. Inspect and modify API calls as necessary. For a more streamlined solution, consider Apidog, which simplifies the process, especially for mobile apps.

Comment: I can use Charles or Fiddler for such case, but does they support automatic checking for APIs requests signatures ?